# Bandwidth Device Variation

Tags: device, bandwidth

this might be a stupid question to some but allow me to ask, does a type of a certain device affect the bandwidth and data transmission? Say for example does a tablet's bandwidth differ from a PC's given that they have the same bandwidth from the router? Thanks in advance for those who will take time to answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the data transfer speed, not materially. As long as the device is fast enough to keep up with the incoming data (a cheap tablet with a slow processor might not be able to process a full HD video stream, for example), the device type doesn't matter. What matters is the network connection, though for wireless better chipsets (e.g., Intel's) will often have better performance than cheaper ones under the same conditions.

Comment: Does that mean there is no fixed formula for bandwidth calculation?

Comment: What do you mean "bandwidth calculation"? What bandwidth are you talking about?

Comment: The amount of data transferred per second over the internet or within the network without internet access.

Comment: The only thing that depends on is the interfaces involved and any configured bandwidth limits (like the limit on your connection to your ISP). A tablet and a laptop connected to the same WiFi network will get about the same network performance. There's no calculation involved.

Comment: What if I would like to block internet access to other users in the network (not sure if this is possible), then say my ISP's bandwidth is 15mbps, do the devices not having the internet access share the same data transfer speed? :)

Comment: This is a question for Superuser.

Comment: Ahm.. sorry.. but what? 0.o?